# An infinite group $G$ always has a countably infinite subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, finite-groups, infinite-groups

I tried to find out whether the following good-looking statement about groups is true. "An infinite group $G$ always has a countably infinite subgroup."

I faced this question while pondering upon the existence of a countably additive, (left) $G$-invariant measure on all of $\mathscr{P}(G)$. If the statement is true, then I believe that the Vitali technique of showing the existence of a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be imitated to establish that such a measure on $\mathscr{P}(G)$ cannot exist. But I am stuck with this group-theoretic obstacle.

To summarize, does an infinite group always has a countably infinite subgroup? Or, does there exist an infinite group, having no countably infinite subgroups? Please enlighten me.

**Addendum** : By a subgroup, I mean to include the case of the group itself. So when $G$ is countable, the question is not very interesting.

Comment: Yes it is true. Any countably infinite subset of $G$ generates a countably infinite subgroup.

Comment: @Holt: Aha! This was the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider $p^n$-th roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$ for a *fixed* prime $p$, but for *all* $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This is an infinite group, but a proper subgroup of it is finite and cyclic.

Think this in following way: let $G_n=\{ z\in\mathbb{C} : z^{p^n}=1\}$; it is cyclic group of order $p^n$, and we have a chain 
$$1\subseteq G_1 \subseteq G_2 \subseteq \cdots;$$
the union of these subgroups (inside $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$) is again a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$. You may then think from this why a proper subgroup of it should be finite.

Comment: This group is itself countable.  The question doesn't specify "proper" subgroup.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear and precise explanation. But I believe that the group itself is countable in this case. I will add this point to the question to make things clear.

Comment: yes, this group is countable.

Comment: +1. Perhaps one could mention the extremely more difficult fact that [given a sufficiently large prime $p$, there is an infinite group all of whose proper, nontrivial subgroups have order $p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group).

Comment: @Caranti: yes, this is nice non-trivial example.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the question, it is an interesting example, so unusually I upvoted an incorrect answer!

Comment: @Holt: I agree. I will take this as the answer to my question!